# Gem not installing most recent changes

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm trying to install lazy_high_charts gem for my Rails project and am having some issues.  The gem installs fine but I'm not seeing the most recent changes to the source in my local copy.  In my gemfile I have

```
gem 'lazy_high_charts'
```

and it works fine.  I also tried

```
gem 'lazy_high_charts', :git => "https://github.com/michelson/lazy_high_charts.git"
```

Basically I want to use [this change](https://github.com/michelson/lazy_high_charts/pull/76) to the gem, but I can't get it installed.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the git option that you are trying to use above for now (I don't think the most recent changes have been packaged into the gem yet), and it looks correct. I usually use the git address, however.

```
gem "lazy_high_charts", git: 'git://github.com/michelson/lazy_high_charts.git'
```

Make sure you re-run `bundle install` and restart your server (kill the running process and run `rails s`)